# Does NASA have any plans for future Mars rovers after Curiosity?

Tags: mars, rovers, curiosity

Curiosity should last a very long time - up to around 14 years.

My question is whether NASA has any plans for a Mars rovers *after* Curiosity. If so, are any specifics known?

Comment: With enough Perseverance, you should have an answer to this question by now. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nasa is planning another rover for a 2020 arrival.  To keep costs down the plan is to use a chassis similar to Curiosity but with a different set of instruments.

NASA's Science Definition Team issued a report earlier this month outlining four major goals for the mission:

- Explore an astrobiologically relevant ancient environment on
  Mars to decipher its geological processes and history, including the
  assessment of past habitability.
- Assess the biosignature preservation potential within the
  selected geological environment and search for potential
  biosignatures.
- Demonstrate significant technical progress towards the
  future return of scientifically selected, well-documented samples to
  Earth.
- Provide an opportunity for contributed Human Exploration &
  Operations Mission Directorate (HEOMD) or Space Technology Program
  (STP) participation, compatible with the science payload and within
  the mission’s payload capacity.

The planetary Society did an in depth [writeup](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/van-kane/20130727-mars-rover-2020-in-depth.html) of the report.  NASA's [report](http://mepag.jpl.nasa.gov/reports/mep_report.html) is available if you'd prefer to read the original.

Concept Sketch for new rover:
[image: Concept Sketch for new rover]

Comment: Costs downs means \$1.5 billion for hardware (not clear if launch included in that cost, but what is \$100-200 million) vs \$2.5 billion for the Curiosity hardware.

Comment: @geoffc Launch should be included.